# Get value returned from angularjs service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a hard time to get to know how to get the value return from a service

**categoryService**:

```
    angular.module("thethaoso").service("categoryService", ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    return ({
        getCatId: getCatId
    });
    function getCatId(sename) {      

        var request = $http.get('/api/category/' + sename);
        return request.then(handleSuccess, handleError);
    }

    function handleError(response) {
        if (!angular.isObject(response.data) ||
            !response.data.message
            ) {

            return ($q.reject("An unknown error occurred."));
        }
        // Otherwise, use expected error message.
        return ($q.reject(response.data.message));

    }
    // I transform the successful response, unwrapping the application data
    // from the API response payload.
    function handleSuccess(response) {
        return (response.data);
    }

}]);
```

**Call from a controller:**

```
     categoryService.getCatId(sename).then(function (Id) {
               $scope.categoryId=Id;
            });

 console.log($scope.categoryId) >> undefined, i guess the service is not yet completed.
 $scope.$on('tabParent', function (event, data) {
               console.log('hello'); **>> get the message**
               anotherService.abc($scope.categoryId) .... **>> fail**
          });
```

I try $timeout with 2000-3000 ms, it works but that would be too late

also i tried to put $scope.$on inside the categoryService but it never calls

```
 categoryService.getCatId(sename).then(function (Id) {
           $scope.categoryId=Id;
           $scope.$on('tabParent', function (event, data) {
               console.log('hello'); >> **>> never reach**
               anotherService.abc($scope.categoryId) .... **>> fail as above**
             }
      });
        })
```

;

What's the fastest way to get the return value outside the **Then block** or a better way to rewrite categoryService ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to do the console log inside the `then` callback function,

```
categoryService.getCatId(sename).then(function (Id) {
           $scope.categoryId=Id;
           console.log($scope.categoryId) 
});
```

Comment: Then we need more detail on where you trigger (`emit` or `broadcast`) function. Seems like you need to wait until `categoryId` is loaded .